# How to search case insensitive using wildcard elastic search java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, wildcard, query-builder

I want to search case insensitive using wildcard.

```
    BoolQueryBuilder paramFilter = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    paramFilter.must(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(field, "*"+key+"*"));
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are running Elasticsearch > v7.10, you can set the `case_insensitive` parameter of the wildcard query to `true`.

otherwise, you can add to the mapping of your field a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) with a [custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) that sets a `keyword` tokenizer and a `lowercase` filter to the field's string. This way, you'll be able to run your wildcard query against the multi-field.